# Nodejs request module: How to be sure the response received is sent on HTTPS?

Tags: node.js, https

I am using an API and I want to make **only** https requests to the endpoint.
The endpoint however doesn't mandate https, it would respond on http as well.

The following is the code that I use to make https requests to the API:

```
  var options = {
    url: "https://something.com",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    agentOptions: {
        cert: fs.readFileSync(certFile),
        key: fs.readFileSync(keyFile),
        rejectUnauthorized: true
    }
  };
    var fetchToken = function(options) {
        request({
            url: options.url,
            method: options.method,
            headers: options.headers,
            body: body,
            agentOptions: options.agentOptions
        },function(err,res){

        });
      }
```

I am using [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#tlsssl-protocol) module in sending the request to the endpoint. Now how can I be sure that the response I received from the endpoint is infact sent via **https**, not http.

Answer (score 0):

If you sent your request to https endpoint, and the server doesn't redirect https request to http, then you communicate to the server through https.

Comment: How might I know that the server has not redirected to http?

Comment: From the documentation that you linked to: followRedirect - follow HTTP 3xx responses as redirects (default: true). This property can also be implemented as function which gets response object as a single argument and should return true if redirects should continue or false otherwise. -- Use this to determine if it is redirected to an http URL and abort.